# Cannot find local module in typescript error on node

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm new to typescript my problem is that local module i created I can't use

./route/routes.ts

```js
import routes from 'next-routes'
                           
let route = new routes()

route.add('index', '/:name')

export default route
```

and in my server.ts

```js
import route from "./route/routes"
```

but when i run `npm run start` then i get the following error

> Cannot find module "./route/routes"

this is my tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

and my package.json

```json
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "babel-node --presets es2015 server.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.ts",
    "build": "next build",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production babel-node --presets es2015 server.ts"
  },
  "author": "Test",
  "license": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "next": "^9.0.5",
    "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.31",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.2",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "nextjs-sitemap-generator": "^0.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "typescript": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

i'm getting error since i migrate to typescript from js

Note: I try to find solution search online seems i can't find really good one

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try moving routes.ts, to wherever your server.ts file is present, update the import statement, and see if it works